# firebase phone authentication not sending sms, got this Error [SmsRetrieverHelper] Timed out waiting for SMS

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm having a problem with firebase phone authentication, yesterday I was testing login with phoneNumber but it didn't work. I tested it with different devices, smsCode doesn't send as to verify login. two weeks ago it was just working fine

I tried to upgrade all the packages including firebase_core and firebase_auth but nothing has changed.

```
firebase_core: ^2.4.0
cloud_firestore: ^4.2.0
firebase_auth: ^4.2.1
```

this is my code:

```
ElevatedButton(
    onPressed: () {
      if (otpVisibility) {
        verifyOTP();
      } else {
        loginWithPhone();
      }
    },
    child: Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 1.h, horizontal: 1.h),
      child: Text(
        otpVisibility ? "verify" : "login",
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.sp, fontFamily: 'Cairo'),
      ),
    ),
),
```

this is the error I keep getting:

```
W/BpBinder( 2464): Slow Binder: BpBinder transact took 433ms, interface=com.google.android.gms.auth.api.phone.internal.ISmsRetrieverApiService, code=1 oneway=false
W/FirebaseAuth( 2464): [SmsRetrieverHelper] Timed out waiting for SMS.
```

```
 void loginWithPhone() async {
    auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
      phoneNumber:_prefix + phoneController.text,
      verificationCompleted: (PhoneAuthCredential credential) async {
        await auth.signInWithCredential(credential).then((value) {
          if (value.user != null) {
            print("Done !!");
            print("You are name saved successfully");
            print("You are logged in successfully");
          } else {
            print("Failed!!");
          }
        }).catchError((e) {
          Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'Something Went Wrong: ${e.toString()}');
        });
      },
      verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException e) {
        print(e.message);
      },
      codeSent: (String verificationId, int resendToken) {
        otpVisibility = true;
        verificationID = verificationId;
        setState(() {});
      },
      codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationId) {},
      timeout: const Duration(seconds: 20),
    );
  }

  void verifyOTP() async {
    PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
        verificationId: verificationID, smsCode: otpController.text);

    await auth.signInWithCredential(credential).then((value) {
      print("You are logged in successfully");
      uploadUserInfoToFirebase();
      _nameSaver();
      Fluttertoast.showToast(
          msg: "You are logged in successfully",
          toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
          gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
          timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
          backgroundColor: KInActiveColor,
          textColor: Colors.white,
          fontSize: 12.sp);
      Navigator.push(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()));
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm facing the same problem as you, but I figured it why it's not sending it sometimes, for me its because of the weak/slow internet connection that the sms verification "times out", but I haven't figured a decent approach to solve this issue.

Comment: @NiiTii for me the problem was upgrading firebase_core and firebas_auth to the latest versions, i guess it's a bug as i found while looking for a solution which was downgrading to a lower version till it works and it did work after using that solution.... hope that help you somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, you are registering the same number, try deleting the number from Firebase/authentication/users or register a different number

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7QGC.png)

Answer (score -1):

```
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
        phoneNumber: '${_prefix}${phoneController.text}',
        verificationCompleted: (PhoneAuthCredential credential) async {
          await auth.signInWithCredential(credential).then((value) {
          if (value.user != null) {
            print("Done !!");
            print("You are name saved successfully");
            print("You are logged in successfully");
          } else {
            print("Failed!!");
          }
        }).catchError((e) {
          Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'Something Went Wrong: ${e.toString()}');
        });
        },
        verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException e) {
          print(e.message);
        },
        codeSent: (String verificationId, int resendToken) {
        otpVisibility = true;
        verificationID = verificationId;
        setState(() {});
      },
      codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationId) {},
      timeout: const Duration(seconds: 20),
    );
        timeout: Duration(seconds: 120));
  }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: this still not working for me, I've tried almost every solution I could find.
Android Device Verification (DEPRECATED) is enabled, Phone Authentication in firebase is enabled too, I already add SHA certificate fingerprints in firebase, android.permission.INTERNET in  AndroidManifest.xml was added too... I don't know what is wrong with it @Laxit Ramani

Comment: can you share the repo link of your project with me?